# Excel VBA : How to make a global event Global_beforsave()

Tags: vba, events, excel

i need detect for each file (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsb, ...) open in excel many properties before saving.

in *.xlsm file i include Workbook_BeforeSave() in thisWorkbook but is avalaible only for thisWorkbook.

i'll wish include a global event in *.xlam file but i don't no how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Charles link shows, you must use a class module to catch events from other objects.

My suggestion is to reuse `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
'App variable which should be assigned to current Application instance:
Public WithEvents App As Excel.Application

'Use open event on your workbook to assign App
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

'Code catching WorkbookBeforeSave event on App
Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "Workbook "; Wb.Name; " is about to be saved..."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

See Chip Pearson's writeup on Application Events
[here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)